# css @top-left doesn't work using DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using dompdf to create a pdf page.In each page i have to display the dynamic content from database.

When i try this, it's not working for me.

```
@page { 
    margin: 20px 30px 60px 70px; 
    @top-left{content:element(header);}
} 
foreach($types as $t){
    $html=$html."<div class='header'>".$t->head_name."</div>";
}
```

Comment: Insufficient information provided

Comment: Please be more specific, as to what exactly `it's not works for me` means. You get a white page, fatal error, warning, not the desired result, no result at all, etc?

Comment: s it displays nothing

Comment: @top-left{content:element(header);} is it right?

Comment: dompdf does not yet support this CSS declaration (still working on fully supporting CSS2).